# Use NVM To Install Latest NodeJS For Specific Major Version

Tags: nvm

I want to install the latest minor/patch version of NodeJS 4 using `nvm`. I don't just want "latest", because that would be NodeJS 8 or whatever later, potentially breaking-change version is out now.

If it were an `npm` dependency, I would be able to say `nvm install "^4"`, but that doesn't work. Is there a simple command to do this? If there isn't, is there something I can do on the command line to find the latest version and install it in a one-liner that works on both Windows and Unix-based consoles?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(nvm maintainer here)

If you run `nvm --help` (make sure you're using the latest version of `nvm`), you'll see a description of all the things `nvm` supports. Specifically, `nvm` does not support semver ranges, however, `nvm install 4` or `nvm install 4.x` will install the latest available version of node 4.

Separately, you can use `nvm install --lts=argon` (and `nvm alias default lts/argon` if you want to peg to the LTS line specifically instead of just v4.

Comment: In version 1.1.7 the install 4.x is removed, use install 4 instead.

Comment: nvm has no version 1.1.7 - perhaps you mean `nvm-windows`?

Comment: just tried `nvm install 10` and thats installed 10.0.0 rather than the latest 10

Comment: @HenryIng-Simmons if you're using nvm.sh (and not nvm-windows), then that shouldn't be the case; please file an issue if so.

Comment: nvm only works on POSIX, so on Windows this requires WSL. `nvm-windows` is an unrelated project that works only on windows.

Comment: Is there any similar command for `nvm-windows`? I saw in the source code it's supposed to work the same but it doesn't.